# Oracle enterprise manager Net Services Administration refuses SYS login

Tags: oracle, networking, service, oracle-enterprise-manager

To configure heterogenous services for connecting to a SQL-SERVER 2005,  we are trying to configure the Oracle 11gR2 database via EM.
We login using the SYS account and when we click on the listener link , Net Services Administration login page comes up, when we supply the same username , SYS , it throws out error : 
" Validation Error 
 ERROR: Invalid username and/or password"
We are sure of the username and the password , if it was invalid it would be impossible to login as SYS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener runs outside the database, and if I recall correctly when NSA prompts you it asks for the *host* login. You need to give the operating system credentials for a user in the DBA group.

Comment: Alex, thank you very much , will try it now.If not we will create such a user.

Comment: The group name might vary depending on platform; and not sure if anything changed in 11g. More of a pointer than an answer really!

Comment: Alex, BTW, Oracle DBMS is running on RHEL 5, for Windows it is written to check on ORA_DBA user group, how can we checkout for that type of user? Anything about the procedure as keypoints would be great.

Comment: Not sure, but I'd start by seeing which user owns the `listener.ora` file on the server, and if it has group write permission then which group that is (I'd guess `dba`); and either connect as the owner or as any member of the group.

Comment: username is oracle, and member of oinstall group

Comment: I guess that is the one : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/em_manage.htm#ADMQS0352

Comment: you are right, to do such an operation ,a user in dba /oinstall group is required, we have checked it by "#history |less" to see the group assignments during installation, but still cannot start the listener using em and lsnrctl status shows a listener is running. Running one is LISTENER and the offline listener is LISTENER_oracledb , oracledb is also the host name, could EM concatanate these two with underscore or are they different listeners?

Comment: played with targets.xml file , re-entered $ORACLE_HOME value, stopped & started listener, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple..

Just make sure that you have logged in with admin account in your windows system.
If oracle is asking for OS credentials, provide your OS credentials(your windows admin username/password).
give username as "admin"
and password as"your-password".

worked for me!!